# I'd like to change the shell script instruction to the one available in the terminal

Tags: applescript, bash, script, zsh

```
do shell script "bless -mount /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/ -legacy -setBoot -nextonly" password "0000" with administrator privileges
tell application "System Events"
    restart
end tell
```

I want to make the script written above available at the terminal.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to change "do shell script" to "oascript-e" written in the front, but it doesn't run on the terminal.

Comment: You don't need a wrapper for a shell script :-)

Comment: Sorry for the wrong question...I want to access my iMac from my MacBook to ssh and execute the command written above.

Comment: No, all fine, it's just sometimes difficult to see with which part of scripting people struggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell script part doesn't need a wrapper to run in a shell, only the AppleScript part. You should be able to run the following two lines in Terminal (assuming you are an admin user):

```
sudo bless -mount /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/ -legacy -setBoot -nextonly
osascript 'tell application "System Events" to restart'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering :-)
Is there any way to enter the password in advance?